# Azure IoT dev kit bootloader

Tags: iot, azure-iot-hub

building a product utilizing EWM3166 module used in Azure IoT devkit and would like to customize the bootloader.
where can I find the source code for Azure IoT devkit AZ3166 bootloader?

Comment: What bootloader?   The devkit seems to have an on-board ST-LINK.  The STM32F4 inside the module will have an immutable, closed source ROM bootloader but it's not clear that would be in use.  If there's a custom bootloader in flash you'd first need to identify it.  Generally questions seeking to find an off-site resource aren't a fit here.   As a piece of advice, you *definitely* want to bring out the SWD pins to where you can connect an ST-LINK with a header and also spring pins for production, and you probably want a UART, too, *even* if your product is intended to be USB.

Comment: please see [link](https://microsoft.github.io/azure-iot-developer-kit/docs/firmware-upgrading/)

Comment: The EWM3166 bootloader is proprietary code from MXChip. So it's necessary to contact with them in order to get it.